# C: Access 'char' in specific memory location?

Tags: c, memory, memory-management

I was interested in accessing portions of memory I had allocated to get a better understanding of things, lets say I allocate 10 bytes with `malloc` and `printf("%p", &foo)` returns `0xff0a`, would I be able to allocate `0xff0a->0xff1a` (my hexadecimal math is bad at the moment) and access any one of those individual bytes?

I think I recall being used the keyword `volatile` along with a memory address for this, I am not sure what that code was able to do though..

I guess what I mean is how do I access a random byte in memory, cast as a char or integer that I can store in a pointer for accessing later on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll assume you want to access a single byte from a multi-byte type such as an int or a short.  The common idiom is to cast the address to a char* and deference that like so:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int foo = 0xDEADBEEF;
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        printf("byte %d of foo is x%02X\n", i, *((unsigned char*)&foo + i));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

#### Output

```
$ ./a.out
byte 0 of foo is xEF
byte 1 of foo is xBE
byte 2 of foo is xAD
byte 3 of foo is xDE
```

***Note*** The reason it looks backwards is due to x86 being little endian

Comment: Ah yes, this is a lot more clear than accessing "memory location 0x... of integer foo" to get a single byte. This clears up a lot :)

Comment: I understood a lot of that so I feel better about the subject. Hehe. Thanks for the examples.

Answer (score 3):

`printf("%p", &foo)` prints the address of the pointer variable `foo`, *not* the address contained in `foo` (which is the one that came from `malloc`).  You actually want:

```
printf("%p", (void *)foo);
```

If you wish to access the 10 bytes in memory pointed to by `foo`, you can simply use:

```
char *p = foo;
```

and then access `p[0]` through `p[9]`.

Comment: How would I know where the pointer is pointing too? How can I access the memory location into a pointer if only memory address (0xffaa) is known? Maybe my questions a _bit_ silly.

Comment: the pointer points to the start of foo, when you specify an offset like caf mentioned, you are not changing the pointer, it still points to the start. e.g. &p[2] points to the same place as p + 2

Comment: @John: If you wish to make a pointer point at a specific location, you can use `char *p = (char *)0xffaa` - but note that the result is implementation-defined, it does not have to do anything sensible.

Answer (score 0):

If you allocate 10 bytes from `0xff0a`, the address range is: `0xff0a` to `0xFF14`.

`volatile` forces the compiler to grab the stored value at that location every time.  This has uses in hardware programming and multi-threaded applications.

This example stores the address of the int x into the pointer p:

```
int x = 5;
int * p = &x; //assign address of (operator &) x into a pointer
printf("%d\n", *p); // will display 5
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use a union in order to always apply the same bunch of code to loop over the bytes area of your variable. The member 'byte' will always point to the same address as the others. You can include it into a struct in order to keep the size along with the union. A the end, you just call a function to print out or check the content of a bunch of memory...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <string.h>

union byteMap {
  char* addressString;
  void* addressInt;
  unsigned char* byte;
};

struct structByteMap {
  size_t size;
  union byteMap map;
};

int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {

  struct structByteMap map;

  if (argc > 1) {
    int temp = strtoimax(argv[1], NULL, 10);
    map.map.addressInt = &temp;
    map.size = sizeof(int);
  } else {
    map.map.addressString = "HELLO, YES HELLO";
    map.size = strlen(map.map.addressString);
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < map.size; i++) {
    printf("byte %d of param is x%02X\n", i, *(map.map.byte + i));
  }

}
```